# Trino Client Rest api authentication

Tags: rest, ldap, presto, trino, presto-jdbc

I am trying to call trino Client REST Api endpoint, my trino is ldap authenticated, is there any documentation for all rest api endpoints exposed by trino so that I can login and post queries to trino cluster ?

is there any java/python snippet available for connecting trino with LDAP ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a full api reference, but there is some limited documentation here: https://trino.io/docs/current/develop/client-protocol.html

I found the API supported basic auth passing the ldap credentials.